# pip in Jupyter (VS code) missing one package (llama-cpp-python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pip

I have built llama-cpp-python with CUBLAS according to the instructions. It works just fine when executing in terminal, however yields the ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter. It worked fine previously when the package was installed without CUBLAS.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from llama_cpp import Llama
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_cpp'
```

If I run `%pip list` in Jupyter, the package is not on the list, however it does show up if I run this command in the terminal. This one package is the only difference between the two lists.
I am using Jupyter in VS code. I have double checked that whether I run from Jupyter or from the terminal I have the same output for `sys.executable` and `sys.path`. I have also checked that `!pip show pip` in Jupyter and `pip show pip` give the same output.

Comment: maybe try `pip show` on a random package and look if the directories match. Do you have multiple python installations?

Comment: @NoBlockhit The directories from `pip show` match too. Unfortunately I have several installations, including two anaconda installations but it is difficult to get around as it is a machine managed by my organization - hence all the path and executable checks

Comment: a dirty trick would be to just install it again

Comment: ^ from jupyter notebooks of course

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have chosen the correct jupyter kernel:

[image]

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook) for more details.

Another way is to run cell `!pip install llama-cpp-python` in your jupyter notebook.